# Is my S3 bucket publicly writable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to work out whether my S3 bucket is publicly writable.

Here is the ACL:
[image]
Here is the bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket.name/*"
    }
]
}
```

I am trying to use S3 CLI: `echo "hello" | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket.name/file.csv --region eu-west-1 --no-sign-request`

However I get the: `upload failed: - to s3://bucket.name/file.csv An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`

Is my bucket safe from public write?

Background:

Got the application and trying to find weak points / auditing. Probably the easiest would be to not give the "write" access to anyone in ACLs. However the point is to not make any changes to the system / code, just find the weak points.

Comment: It looks like to me that you#ve set your bucket publicly gettable, rather than writeable. Try settnig Action to `*` and see if that helps?

Comment: S3 authorization uses the union of all the IAM policies, S3 bucket policies, and S3 ACLs that apply with DENY being the default, and with explicit DENY trumping ALLOW. You're using a combination of an S3 bucket policy (allowing everyone to invoke GetObject) and a bucket-level ACL (allowing everyone to read/write). This combination allows everyone to write to the bucket. And indeed it does - I just tried it with your echo hello command and was able to put objects as an unauthenticated user. You're seeing AccessDenied, however, so are you sure that there are no more policies than shown above?

Comment: Thanks for your try @jarmod. Do you have an idea where else I should look like to find out potentially more policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bucket policy, as shown, only grants Read permissions. It does not grant Write permissions.

However, your bucket ACL is:

[image: bucket ACL]

This is currently permitting anyone in the world to read from AND write to your bucket.

Since access is granted if ANY of these methods grant access, then **Yes, your bucket is publicly writable**.

**Test of Scenario**

Here's what I did:

- Account A: Created Bucket A, assigned "public permissions" of READ and WRITE for Object access (no Permissions access -- not necessary)
- Account B: Used the AWS CLI with a User from a different account (Account B) and successfully did `aws s3 ls` on the bucket and `aws s3 cp` to copy an object to the bucket

The fact that the call was made from an IAM User from a different AWS Account shows that the **Object access** permissions were granting read and write access.

Comment: Thanks John, that's how I understood the settings (config merge between ACL and bucket policy) as well, however I can not publicly write to my bucket as per my question. Do you have an idea why this might be?

Comment: I've added details of how I performed the test.

Comment: Thanks @John. I was making mistake, writing to wrong bucket. I've improved permissions on my side and now it's safe. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Thanks to you all I've discovered public open write permissions on S3 bucket on the UK Gov Companies House site. You could replace their PDFs on the Filling history (e.g. https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/02752451/filing-history/MzEwOTE0NzI1OWFkaXF6a2N4/document?format=pdf&download=0) and replace it with your file. I've reported it on Twitter and it was fixed very quickly: